# Receive incorrect resultCode in Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult when request permission from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an app with targetSdkVersion = 23, compileSdkVersion = 23 with main activity setup like following

```
- HomeActivity (AppCompatActivity)
  - FragmentA (V4 Fragment)
    - ViewPager
      - NestedFragmentA (V4 Fragment)
      - NestedFragmentB (v4 Fragment)
      - NestedFragmentC (v4 Fragment)
      - NestedFragmentD (v4 Fragment)
  - Fragment B (V4 Fragment)
  - Fragment C (V4 Fragment)
```

And in HomeActivity

```
public static final String PERMISSION = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    Log.i("Logger", "Request Code: " + String.valueOf(requestCode));

    // Handle permission request result
}
```

I read this answer from @CommonsWare,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33170531/760363

that the onRequestPermissionsResult in nested fragment will never gets called (in my case, it result will return to HomeActivity) but I'm fine with that, I'll manually notify fragment of the result.

But the problem is, when I request for permission in HomeActivity, everything works fine.

**HomeActivity**

```
// Request permission from HomeActivity
// Supply 101 as request code, get 101 back

@Override
public void clickSomething(View v) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{PERMISSION}, 101);
}

// Logcat
Logger: Request Code: 101 <<< CORRECT
```

But in **FragmetnA** or **NestedFragmentA**, when I request from nested fragment, the requestCode that return to HomeActivity has changed

**FragmentA**

```
// Request permission from FragmentA
// Supply 102 as request code, get 358 back

@Override
public void clickAnotherThing(View v) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{HomeActivity.PERMISSION}, 102);
}

// Logcat
Logger: Request Code: 358 <<< INCORRECT
```

**NestedFragmentA**

```
// Request permission from NestedFragmentA
// Supply 103 as request code, get 615 back

@Override
public void clickDifferentThing(View v) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{HomeActivity.PERMISSION}, 103);
}

// Logcat
Logger: Request Code: 615 <<< INCORRECT
```

Do you have any idea what would cause this issue?

Comment: you cant call requestpermission from nested frgament...please visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169455/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-dialog-fragment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onRequestPermissionsResult not being called in dialog fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169455/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-dialog-fragment)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would not negate the fact that `"Nested Fragments do not receive request permissions (onRequestPermissionsResult()) callback"`.

But what I will do here is to explain the behavior observed by you regarding the different "weird" request codes received in the container activity for the `requestPermissions()` made by the fragments and the nested fragments.

To explain this let's consider your example -

```
- HomeActivity (AppCompatActivity)
  - FragmentA (V4 Fragment)
    - ViewPager
      - NestedFragmentA (V4 Fragment)
      - NestedFragmentB (v4 Fragment)
      - NestedFragmentC (v4 Fragment)
      - NestedFragmentD (v4 Fragment)
  - Fragment B (V4 Fragment)
  - Fragment C (V4 Fragment)
```

Implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` only in `HomeActivity, FragmentA and NestedFragmentA` for better understanding with logs printing the request code received

```
    @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            Log.d("debug", "req code :: " + requestCode);     
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
```

Also request certain permission from `FragmentA` and `NestedFragmentA`. Let's take exmaple of location permissions

```
 requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 102);
```

Now  whenever we `requestPermissions()` from fragments or nested fragments, it  calls `Fragment class's requestPermissions()` which in turn calls `FragmentHostCallback's onRequestPermissionsFromFragment()` which in turn calls `FragmentActivity's requestPermissionsFromFragment()` . Now here lies the transformation of your request code.
After validating your request code, it calls

```
ActivityCompat's requestPermissions()
```

**BUT**

with the transformed request code -

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,((fragment.mIndex + 1) << 8) + (requestCode & 0xff));
```

So the changed request code is -

```
((fragment.mIndex + 1) << 8) + (requestCode & 0xff)
```

where `fragment.mIndex` is the fragment level . So for immediate fragment (means directly a child of the container activity), it will be  "0"
and for immediate nested fragment(means the fragment immediately inside a fragment) it will be "1" and it will get incremented based on how deep your fragment is nested.

In our case, for `FragmentA`, request code changes to

```
 (((0 + 1) << 8) + (102 & 0xff)) which computes to 358
```

And for `NestedFragmentA`, request code changes to

```
(((1 + 1) << 8) + (102 & 0xff)) which computes to 614
```

Now we know where the request code changes. Let's continue from  `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`. So we are aware of `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` since we use this method to request permissions from activities.
Also, we know this will do some operations and the user will be shown the permission popup to accept/deny the requested permission.

Now we'll come to `onRequestPermissionsResult()`. When the user will accept/deny then `onRequestPermissionsResult()` of the container activity will get invoked  because ultimately `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`was called. 
Let's say you accept/deny the permission from `FragmentA` So you'll get the log-

```
 req code ::358
```

After that

```
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
```

will invoke `FragmentActivity's onRequestPermissionsResult()` which in turn performs some validation and  call

```
frag.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode&0xff, permissions, grantResults);
```

Bow you can see the request code passed in `frag.onRequestPermissionsResult()` is different. `requestCode` was `358` and after `&0xff` it becomes `102`  again.
 Voila !!
That means although we got different request code (`358`) in `HomeActivity's  onRequestPermissionsResult()`, yet we are calling `FragmentA's onRequestPermissionsResult()` with the original request code (`102`)
So we will get these logs from `FragmentA` -

```
 req code ::358
```

Now coming to `NestedFragmentA`. Let's say you accept/deny the permission from `NestedFragmentA` So you'll get the log in `HomeActivity` -

```
 req code ::614
```

But we know `onRequestPermissionsResult()` will not be invoked for nested fragments so we won't get any logs in `NestedFragmentA's onRequestPermissionsResult()`

I guess I have explained the reason why we get different request codes in the container activity for the `requestPermissions()` made by the fragment and nested fragments.

So I'd say that for the fragments which are not nested  `requestPermissions()` from the fragments only and implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` there only and not in the container activity.
For nested fragments, one should `requestPermissions()`  for the permissions required by the nested fragments from the parent fragment only . It seems this is the only workaround.

Comment: Further questions, 1.) Can I say, if I don't override onRequestPermissionsResult or if I call super in container activity, the FragmentA will received correct code? 2.) Is this behaviour same for both Activity and ActivityCompat?

Comment: 1. Yes        2.  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() in turn finally invoke activity.requestPermissions()

Comment: So, there's no fix

Comment: The fix is to use ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), ... instead of requestPermisions(...
source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33729728/8719655