# handling Permissions in a single class in android

Tags: java, android

For handling permissions in android M+, I want to write a single class, namely PermissionHandler class, to handle all the permission-related work so that I can easily use the same class in any project without making changes to the calling activity by calling only the constructor:

```
           new PermissionHandler(CallingActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, new PermissionHandler.PermissionGranted() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted() {
                    doWhatever();
                }
            });
```

My PermissionHandler is:

```
public class PermissionHandler implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback{
.
.
.
public PermissionHandler(AppCompatActivity callingActivity, String permission, PermissionGranted permissionGranted) {
        this.permission = permission;
        this.permissionGranted = permissionGranted;
        this.callingActivity= callingActivity;
        askForPermission();

}

private void askForPermission() {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission)) {
                    showAlertDialog();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(callingActivity,permissionsArray, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
                }
            } else {
                permissionGranted.onPermissionGranted();
            }
}

    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissionGranted.onPermissionGranted();
            } else {
                onPermissionIsNotGranted();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is that `onRequestPermissionsResult` which is supposed to be invoked when `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(callingActivity,permissionsArray, PERMISSION_REQUEST)` is called is never invoked.
What I found out is that this is due to android calling `callingActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult` which does not exist in the callingActivity and is passed to PermissionHandler.
I also considered using Reflection and Proxies to resolve this issue at runtime, but no success.

Comment: Why would it? It's perfectly fine to ask Android related questions here.

Comment: This could be helpful to you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33170531/6127411

Comment: @jankigadhiya, No, I have neither of those ...

Comment: @AliNematiHayati did you find a solution for your problem? I'm on the same situation! thaks

Answer (score 1):

As far as i searched i found that its a bug in android. You can see the [live issue here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189121). `onRequestPermissionsResult()` will not be called in any other class then the activity it is called by.

For more details refer this question : [onRequestPermissionsResult not being called in dialog fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169455/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-dialog-fragment). this user having the same problem as yours.

> Creating a Common class for requesting permissions is a really good
>   attempt but my friend, we need to find an alternative for handling
>   `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

Answer (score 0):

[according](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37272693/3214950) [Janki Gadhiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6127411/janki-gadhiya) answers, I write procedure like

```
public static WhatYouWould fCustomRequestPermissionsResult(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults,...)
```

in *My PermissionHandler* class and do what I would, then in for example *MainActivity.java*, I call that in *onRequestPermissionResult* :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    ActiveUtility.CheckPermission.fCustomRequestPermissionsResult(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using for requesting single permission on Android 11. compileSdk=30, minSdk=30, targetSdk=30

PermittedTask.java

```
public abstract class PermittedTask {
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> launcher;
    private String permission;
    private AppCompatActivity activity;

    public PermittedTask(AppCompatActivity activity, String permission) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.permission = permission;
        this.launcher =  activity.registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
                        if(result) {
                            granted();
                        } else {
                            denied();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    protected abstract void granted();

    protected void denied() {}

    private void showRequestPermissionRationale() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    builder.setTitle("Permissions needed")
            .setMessage("App needs permissions to do that. You can allow or deny in next screen. Proceed?")
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    launcher.launch(permission);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    denied();
                }
            })
            .show();
    }

    public void run() {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            granted();
        } else if(activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)) {
            showRequestPermissionRationale();
        } else {
            launcher.launch(permission);
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //...
    
    private PermittedTask scanTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        
        //...       
        
        scanTask = new PermittedTask(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) {
            @Override
            protected void granted() {
                startDiscovery();
            }
        };
        
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {                
                scanTask.run();
            }
        });
        
        //...
    }
    
    private void startDiscovery() {    
        //...    
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (checkPermission(PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

            addToneToStorage();

        } else {

            requestForPermission(PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        }
```

> BaseActivity

```
public static final int PERMISSION_RECORD_AUDIO = 1;
public static final int PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 2;
public static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 3;

public boolean checkPermission(int permission) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, getPermission(permission)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Debug.e("PERMISSION_CHECK_PERMISSION_FALSE", "-" + permission);
        return false;
    } else {
        Debug.e("PERMISSION_CHECK_PERMISSION_TRUE", "-" + permission);
        return true;
    }

}

public void requestForPermission(final int permission) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            getPermission(permission))) {

        Debug.e("PERMISSION_NEEDED", "-" + permission);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.text_permission_rationale));

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BaseActivity.this, new String[]{getPermission(permission)}, permission);

            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    } else {

        Debug.e("PERMISSION_ALLOW", "-" + permission);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{getPermission(permission)}, permission);

    }
    // END_INCLUDE(camera_permission_request)
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {


    if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Camera permission has been granted, preview can be displayed

        Debug.e("PERMISSION_ALLOWED", "-" + requestCode);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.text_permission_granted));

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();

    } else {

        Debug.e("PERMISSION_DENIED", "-" + requestCode);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.text_permission_not_granted));

        // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}

public String getPermission(int permis) {

    String permission = null;

    switch (permis) {
        case PERMISSION_RECORD_AUDIO:
            permission = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;
            Debug.e("PERMISSION", "-" + permission);
            return permission;
        case PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            permission = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
            Debug.e("PERMISSION", "-" + permission);
            return permission;
        case PERMISSION_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            permission = Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
            Debug.e("PERMISSION", "-" + permission);
            return permission;
    }
    return permission;
}
```

}