# Viewpager snaps to the wrong page after taking a photo

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am currently using a **Viewpager** implementation in my android app. In each of the fragment, there is a **button** that takes a photo and uploads it to an online database. However, due to the new permissions requirement, I needed to ask for permission. Hence, i would need to use the ***onRequestPermissionsResult()*** to continue uploading.

Below is my implementation

this is from the **ViewPager.class** (Since after permission is granted, this method in the Viewpager is called instead of the one in the fragment)

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Permission granted to write and read file
                //Get the current fragment
                List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
                for (Fragment currFragment : fragments) {
                    if (currFragment != null)
                        currFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                                REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO
                                , permissions
                                , grantResults);
                }
            }
            return;
        default: //Do nothing
            return;
    }
}
```

this is from the **fragment** itself

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Permission granted to write and read file
                uploadImage();
            }
            return;
        default: //Do nothing
            return;
    }
}
```

this part

```
List<Fragment> fragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
                    for (Fragment currFragment : fragments) {
                        if (currFragment != null)
                            currFragment.onRequestPermissionsResult(
                                    REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO
                                    , permissions
                                    , grantResults);
                    }
```

is my attempt to find the **correct fragment** that clicked the button and call the **OnRequestPermissionResult()** method.

However, I notice this weird behavior from **Viewpager**.  The way I implemented it is that I click a **Viewholder** from a **RecyclerView**, then that enters that position in the ViewPager.

The weird behavior is that for example, I entered page 2 from the **RecyclerView**. Then i swipe to page 4 and click the upload photo button, after the photo is done(via the in-build camera app), it will switch back to page 2.

Why is that? How do I fix it? Sorry for a lengthy post. Just trying to get as much information out there. Thanks

EDIT: This is how I call the requestPermission

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO) {
        //Request for permission to access file
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //ask for permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        } else {
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
}
```

Is something wrong?

Edit Post: This is the part where I called the notifyDataSetChange()

```
private void loadData() {
    mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<RouteInstructions> mList2 = new ArrayList<RouteInstructions>();

            for (DataSnapshot instructions : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                mList2.add(instructions.getValue(RouteInstructions.class));
            }
            mList = mList2;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mPager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_INDEX, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that the code you posted is relevant to your problem? Shouldn't you show us how you manipulate your fragments list?

Comment: How do you call requestPermission ? As per this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169455/onrequestpermissionsresult-not-being-called-in-dialog-fragment you can see that if you call the support library one it will point back to your fragment directly.. is that a solution for you?

Comment: @KalaBalik What do you mean by how i manipulate fragments list? Are you referring to the getItem() and the getCount() in my FragmentStatePagerAdapter part?

Comment: @Cata I am using the Fragment from the support library, not the dialog fragment. Does it work on Support Library one as well? I am also not using nested fragment like the post mentioned.

Comment: @CodingNoobie Since your `ViewPager` does "weird" things, I was just wondering if your adapter needs updating whenever you modify a fragment in your list. If you are using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` it would be `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @KalaBalik I have used the notifyDataSetChanged() in my loadData() method, which basically get the latest data and put in a Arraylist and then change the data for the adapter. That is when i call the notifyDataSetChange(). I have included the code in the post for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug. Basically, I made the mistake of putting the loadData() method in the onResume() method, hence setting the Viewpager page back to the one it got from that Extra.